# Hide a div based on user email with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, express

I am wondering how to change the contents of a list within a div based on the signed in users account access using javascript or express.

I know in PHP I would use the code

```
if($_SESSION['userUid'] == 'Noodlescoop'){
     //Do stuff here
}
```

But, I want to be able to only show the logout button if the email address of the user, otherwise if the user is an admin, I want them to have access to the reports page and admin panel.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-secondary text-uppercase fixed-top" id="mainNav">
    <div class="container">
      <a class="navbar-brand js-scroll-trigger" href="/dashboard">Chinook Winds Logistics LLC</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right text-uppercase font-weight-bold bg-primary text-white rounded" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        Menu
        <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
          <li class='nav-item mx-0 mx-lg-1'>
            <a href="/admin" class='btn btn-primary'>Admin Panel</a>
          </li>
          <li class='nav-item mx-0 mx-lg-1'>
            <a href="/reports" class='btn btn-primary'>Reports</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item mx-0 mx-lg-1">
            <a href="/users/logout" class="btn btn-primary">Logout</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

I am pretty sure I need to do something similar to this:

```
router.get('/dashboard', ensureAuthenticated,  (req, res) => {
    if(req.user.admin === true){
        res.render('dashboard', {
            name: req.user.name,
            email: req.user.email,
            admin: req.user.admin
    })}
    else{
        res.render('dashboard', {
            name: req.user.name,
            email: req.user.email
        }, function (err, html){
            if(err){
                console.log(err);
            }
            res.send(getElementById(navbarResponsive).hide());
        })
    }
});
```

Edited this a bit, changed the router.get portion. When I log in with an account that is an admin, everything works fine, when I log in with an account that is not an admin it throws the error:

```
ReferenceError: getElementById is not defined
```

Otherwise if there is an easier way to do this, I am open to options :D

Comment: I'd say use their user account instead of their email address, especially if you have access to their user account already (they are logged in).

Comment: ``$(navbarResponsive).hide();)`` is code that would run on the clients browser, but the code ``router.get...`` is the server code. If you want to change the documents structure, you either have to adapt the template rendering on your ``res.render`` call or use custom JavaScript code that is shipped with your rendered template which changes the document during the runtime in the browser.

Comment: I only want to hide the navbarResponsive based on whether or not the user is an admin.

Where would I put the $(navbarResponsive).hide?

Comment: It should be in front end.

Comment: How would I go about doing that? I am still new to JS so I'm not 100% sure where or how to accomplish this.